# disable automatic changes in designer.cs

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, auto-generate

I have created a new button class within my project:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CEditor
{
    public class CustomButton : Button
    {
        public CustomButton()
        {
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);
        }
    } 
}
```

After I drop the custom button on the form, two lines of code are generated in the designer.cs, each producing the same error:

```
namespace CEditor
{
    partial class CEditor
    {
        private CEditor.CustomButton button1;
        // Error:
        // The type name 'CustomButton' does not exist in the type 'CEditor.CEditor'

        this.button1 = new CEditor.CustomButton();
        // Error:
        // The type name 'CustomButton' does not exist in the type 'CEditor.CEditor'
    }
}
```

Everything runs fine, if I remove the "CEditor." parts from both lines, so far so good, but as soon as I generate an event per double-click in the property panel of a control, the designer "repairs" the above lines and I have to delete the "CEditor." parts again, which gets more annoying the more buttons there are.

Is there anything I can do to stop that behavior?

Comment: This is why you shouldn't give your class the same name as its namespace.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx

Comment: You are right, a simple underscore solved this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why [you shouldn't give your class the same name as its namespace](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx).

Change either name (eg, `CEditorControl`) and you'll be fine.